# sipml5 do not hang up automatically at the end of a call

Tags: websocket, webrtc, sip, freeswitch, sipml5

I have a sipml5 web client and I can successfully make a call to it. But when a caller (softphone like linphone) hangs up, the web client is not hanging the call. and the event of sipml.session.call son't show that the caller is already hang up, How can i fix this ?

Nothing find to try.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.